# String range is correct, why still get PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 ..32767)

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_NAME( V_CODE VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    NAME VARCHAR2(242);
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT FACT_NAME
    INTO NAME
    FROM TABLEXXX
    WHERE FACT_CODE = V_CODE;
RETURN NAME;
END;
```

Why even defined VARCHA2 with length 242, it still shows this error? Too strange.

> String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)

Comment: You're are missing one semi-colon `;`. You have a variable `NAME` and table column `NAME`. Add the semi-colon and rename your variables so that they no more conflict with the table column name. The usual convention is to prefix PL/SQL variables e.g. with `v_`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help. The missing semi-colon is the typo when I post this question. Will re-define the variable name to see it works or not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Your code compiles fine for me in 12c, after I create a test table.  You may want to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), perhaps using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Check the column FACT_NAME definition in TABLEXXX like varchar2 length and also verify FACT_CODE is  primary key. Though this might not be your answer but it will help us to understand ur issue in some more details.

Comment: Not sure why above code not work properly. After I changed the variable name by adding prefix to avoid conflict, it works now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_NAME( PV_CODE VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
        LV_NAME VARCHAR2(242);
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT NAME
        INTO LV_NAME
        FROM TABLEXXX
        WHERE NAME_CODE = PV_CODE;
    RETURN LV_NAME;
    END;
/
```

You should use prefix before each variable because they causing conflicts.

Comment: It's better practice to use aliases rather than prefixes, because on rare occasions even prefixes can conflict with column names.